# Tabs in material desing lite like simple ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, material-design-lite

I have a question regarding tabs in material desing lite. Here is sample usage of tabs in mdl.

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs">
  <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
    <a href="#tab1" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab One</a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Tab Two</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active" id="tab1">
    <p>First tab's content.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="tab2">
    <p>Second tab's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looks pretty straightforward for tabs with simple content but what if I have many tabs each with complex content. How can I make the tabs work like simple ActionLinks with all the perks like ripple animation and `is-active` class. My solution was to put link into tabs like this.

```
<div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color--primary-dark">
    @foreach (var tab in Model)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(@tab.Name, "Tab", "Index", null, new { @Class = "mdl-layout__tab" })
    }
</div>
```

But the links are not working and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Obviously I'm doing something wrong or using the tabs for something they weren't designed for.

Comment: It may be the html attributes part of your actionLink helper. You should can't use the "-" hyphen between mdl and layout__tab. Try it like this mdl_layout__tab. MVC is smart enough to know you want a hyphen...it will  turn the underscore in to a hyphen at run time.

Comment: No html is rendering correctly even with usage of hyphen.

Comment: Try building the anchor tag with out the html helper then fill in the blanks with your razor variables...also I'm not familiar with desing lite but shouldn't you give the anchor tags an id? Like...@Html.ActionLink(@tab.Name, "Tab", "Index", null, new { @Class = "mdl-layout__tab" , id="tab1"})